# Postgres: (how) can I output EXPLAIN <query> to a file?

Tags: postgresql, psql, explain

This works:

```
psql -XqAt "<DB_URI>" \
  -c "\copy select 1) to out.sql"
```

**Can `EXPLAIN` be output to a file as well?** If the above `SELECT 1` is prepended with `explain(analyze,buffers,costs,timing,verbose,format json)`

```
psql -XqAt "<DB_URI>" \
  -c "\copy (explain(analyze,buffers,costs,timing,verbose,format json) select 1) to out.sql"
```

this then errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command is incorrect. Youre using \copy but thats only used to copy data from a table to a file not for running sql queries. If im not mistaken this should work:

```
psql -XqAt "<DB_URI>" \
  -o out.sql \
  -c "explain(analyze,buffers,costs,timing,verbose,format json) select 1"
```